# toggleclass not binding click event

Tags: jquery, html

Added a class to my button and trying to launch on onclick event after, not working . pretty simple code why is the event not binding what am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n2WUn/3/

---

```
$(".remove-participant").on("click",function(){
$(this).html('Approve');
$(this).toggleClass('add-participant');
 });

$(".add-participant").on("click",function(){
alert('why no alert?');
$(this).html('Waitlist');
$(this).toggleClass('add-participant');
});
```

Comment: *"toggleclass not binding click event"* Why would it? `toggleClass` has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with event binding.

Comment: Are you really toggling the class add-participant always? are they both the same elements?

Answer (score 2):

You are removing and adding the classes dynamically, so your event binding is no longer available. One way you can fix this is by using event delegation.

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove-participant", function () {
    $(this).html('Approve');
    $(this).toggleClass('add-participant');
});

 $(document).on("click", ".add-participant", function () {
    alert('why no alert?');
    $(this).html('Waitlist');
    $(this).toggleClass('add-participant');
});
```

Instead of `document` use a container selector that exists in DOM at any given point in time.

Looking at your script you can just do with one event handler bind it to another class that you don't toggle (which you need to add the particular element).